# iOS torchActive always return false

Tags: ios, torch

I want to test the torch, so I write some code

```
    guard let camera = camera else {
        return
    }
    if camera.hasTorch {
        do {
            try camera.lockForConfiguration()
            if camera.torchActive {
                if camera.isTorchModeSupported(.Off) {
                    camera.torchMode = .Off
                }
            } else {
                if camera.isTorchModeSupported(.On) {
                    camera.torchMode = .On
                }
            }
            camera.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {

        }
```

}

and the  `camera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)` which is a member variable. Like this `private var camera: AVCaptureDevice?`

The question is I only can make the torchMode = .On, because the torchActive always return flase!!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?